# Tax loss harvesting with stocks and ETFs

Tags: united-states, taxes, wash-sale, tax-loss-harvesting

Suppose I'm taking losses in a set of individual stocks (X, Y, Z ...). What are the US tax implications if I sell all of them, harvest losses for tax purposes, and select an ETF E with significant exposure to X, Y, Z and buy immediately. Would that trigger wash sale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wash sale rule applies to "substantially identical" stock or  options.

An ETF is not a "substantially identical" to any individual stock.  The only way that it would be applicable would be if one owned (or was short) all of the stocks in the ETF.